# Smoke & fire simulation: Cycles material not showing fire

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

Fire is no longer being emitted from my material, even though I have not made changes to my material. The node setup is exactly as I had it before, but now nothing works.

Here's the [.blend](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/686388/posts/stackexchange/explosion-smoke-fire.blend) file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't the material, it's that there are no visible flames in the simulation.

On the "Debris Emitter" object, the *Flame Rate* set set to `.025` If you set it to something like `.25`, the material works fine:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I was just looking through older incremental saves and did find a working one. I was just at the stage of trying to figure out what on earth was different between the older working version and the broken present version. You solved it!

Comment: Something interesting to note: In my earlier working file the Flame Rate was set to 0.025 and yet flames were visible. I think this means that the Flame Rate value required to make flames visible is also dependent on some other variable - but I don't know what that variable might be.

Comment: @Mentalist There is a *Speed* setting in *Domain settings > Smoke Flames > Reaction* which affects the behavior of all flames in the domain. Perhaps it was set lower in the working .blend? (lower = faster burning = more fuel burned at once = larger flame)