# Fire not showing up in final render (Blender Internal)

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, smoke-simulation

Using Blender Render. My simulation works fine in view port.I have tried setting up the textures as people have said but it doesn't help I got one with just smoke working but the one that needs fire doesn't.

#### [blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/38374)

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34403/smoke-fire-simulation-cycles-material-not-showing-fire

Comment: @Mentalist The only problem is I am not using cycles so the material is different.

Comment: I see, thanks for mentioning that. I edited the question title to make that clear. Always best to note which render engine you're using if asking a rendering-related question.

Comment: Follow the directions in the Blender Manual for a minimal solution to both Smoke and Flame when using the Internal Render engine. The specific page is here: [smoke and flame](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/materials/special_effects/volume.html). TC