# Cycles Flame in Smoke Simulation not Rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, smoke-simulation

[image]

I am trying to make an explosion in Blender.

I am having a problem with the smoke simulation with the Cycles rendering engine. More specifically, I have been able to render smoke, but flames do not show up. In the viewport however, everything looks perfectly fine.

The render looks like this:

[image: Smoke, but no flame]

But in the viewport, it is clear that there are flames. Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

> This is NOT a duplicate of [Smoke & fire simulation: Cycles material not showing fire](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34403/smoke-fire-simulation-cycles-material-not-showing-fire) because I have Flame Rate set to 1.0

Comment: Dude add a light! I presume you had no light setup in your scene

Answer (score 12):

It looks that you've used Quick Smoke. Though its material setup is ready to add the fire, it hasn't the shaders to it.

[image]

So you only have to add some nodes to that Input: mainly an Emission connected to an Attribute Node set to *flame*. Eventually, you would need a ColorRamp to color the fire.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The name in the Attribute box must be without capital letter : flame and not Flame

Comment: Probably a good catch.  Perhaps a screen shot attribute box.

Comment: This is not the case. If you had downloaded the provided blend file, you would have seen that that's not the problem. There is no Attribute node in the shader so this couldn't be the answer.