# Fire not showing up in render view

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, smoke-simulation, fire

I have a smoke simulation with fire and it is not showing up in my render viewport.[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45157/cycles-flame-in-smoke-simulation-not-rendering