# Rendering an explosion on a tracked video in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I tracked my footage and put an Explosion in it.
My Problem is when I want to render the Animation I always get a white Image.
How can I render only the Explosion without the White Images in cycles?
It also does this on every Format. Here is also the node Setup for the explosion if it helps you[image]

[image]

Comment: For the filre try this node setup: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2131.png read this post: [Cycles Flame in Smoke Simulation not Rendering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45157/cycles-flame-in-smoke-simulation-not-rendering)

Comment: I tried it but I dont think the node Setup is wrong. I could render it correctly but with a more time consuming method. I applied the camera track to the camera, so there would only be keyframes then I copied the camera and the explosion and pasted them into a new Project, where I could render it.